# add extra binding programatically in Droid using vnext

Tags: mvvmcross

I am using mvvmcross vnext right now.
I have a listitem binded in the the layout like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Item.Name'}}" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_state_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

What I would like to do is to dynamically set binding on the view `item_state_text`. Something like this:

```
if (<some_condition>) 
                myBinding = "{'Text':{'Path':'Item.LegacyStuff'}}";
TextView stateText = mvxBindableListItemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.item_state_text) as TextView;
// create binding
            this.GetService<IMvxBinder>().Bind(this.ViewModel, stateText , myBinding );
```

How can I achieve that

Thanks

Comment: Can you include a bit more information? It's not obvious to me what you are trying to bind to - especially it looks like you are trying to bind the list item to the top level `ViewModel` - which is not really doable in vnext or v3 - within a list item view you have to bind to properties of the list item's individual DataContext not to the top level viewmodel.

Comment: You are right. I was just digging little bit and as you said, it's datacontext that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I wouldn't do this - I wouldn't conditionally add bindings, especially in the case of ListItemViews as these get reused across the list and it would be hard to work out whether the binding was already applied or not.

Instead I'd use:

- Visibility bindings to show/hide the conditional view,
- or I'd use a ValueConverter to do the conditional text conversion.
- or I'd use a custom Adapter to show a different 'cell' dependent on the conditional decision.

---

With that said, if you do want to generate conditional bindings using code-behind inside each cell, and you want to carry on using vNext, then you can do that using code something like:

```
var binder = this.GetService<IMvxBinder>();
var binding = binder.Bind(source, stateText, "{'Text':{'Path':'Item.LegacyStuff'}}").First();
BindingActivity.RegisterBinding(binding);
```

This syntax is easier in v3 where you can use the `FluentBinding` syntax to generate the binding - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#fluent

Comment: Again Stuart. Thanks for your incredible support. I was using converter for that and was also trying the visibility plugin. It thought that may be doing it programatically will make more easier, but not a big deal.

Comment: By the way, we would like to go to v3 at one point. What is the status for it, is it close to be released?

Comment: It's officially in beta still - because we're waiting for xamarin pcl support - but it's the only platform I use. Haven't built any software on vnext since February. Vids on http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com show how stable it is.